# Error: python311.dll was not found when create python app using nuitka

Tags: python, pyinstaller, nuitka

I created an apps program using python, and compile it to executable file using nuitka, in my pc, the file works 100%, but when I share it to other pc (which has the updated python version), it is encountering error:

[python311.dll was not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G3eM.jpg)

why ?

I tried to copy the python311.dll to that PC, still not working